# Python code without highlight when using docker container in vscode

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code

I tried to use docker container in Linux server(Ubuntu) for python programming using ssh remote connection in vscode. The python code can run and debug. However, it cannot be highlighted and therefore I cannot view the source code of the package and there is not syntax check. Why is that and how to solve it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xf1lm.png)

And it appears that the python interpreter was not recongnized correctly.As shown in the following picture:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWk1C.png)

I tried to change `Extensions-Python-Language_Server`  to `Pylance` but it didn't work. And I tried something else, but nothing worked.

**supplementary**:

I added the python interpreter when I tried to fix this problem. I think that's why the code can run and debug. But, although it can run and debug after adding python interpreter, the code are still unhighlighted.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2EPr.png)

**Possible Solution**:

The problem seems to be solved after I saw a warning from vscode. I changed the workspace folder smaller(the folder only include my code files) and it worked. As shown in the following picture:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1WCq.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4A2M.png)

**More question**:

Although the problem seens to be sloved, vscode still warns me about the "large workspace folder", maybe there are still some problems that have not been solved. If you have any idea, I look forward to hearing your advices and ideas.

Comment: I think the second issue is causing the first issue.  Without an interpreter loaded, the packages aren't in `__path__` so VSCode doesn't know where to go to find the package source code.  However, how are you running and debugging if VSCode isn't recognizing a valid Python interpreter as having been selected?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. I think I added the python interpreter when I tried to fix this problem. I have edited this question for clarity.  
I agree with you about  the second issue is causing the first issue. But, although it can run and debug after adding python interpreter, the code are still unhighlighted.

Comment: What is "highline"?

Comment: sry, highlight.

Comment: Whether to set `editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled` to `true`?

Comment: editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled is "configByTheme", but it worked anyway. You can check the "possible solution" edited in the text.  Thank you everybody for the advice and inspiration, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you find the solution, Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Possible Solution**:

The problem seems to be solved after I saw a warning from vscode. I changed the workspace folder smaller(the folder only include my code files) and it worked. As shown in the following picture:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOZjj.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1p7dn.png)

**More question**:

Although the problem seens to be sloved, vscode still warns me about the "large workspace folder", maybe there are still some problems that have not been solved. I suggest to view the official documentation https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux#_visual-studio-code-is-unable-to-watch-for-file-changes-in-this-large-workspace-error-enospc  for more detailed solution. If you have any idea, I look forward to hearing your advice and answer.

Comment: Without actually seeing your workspace and all of the related files and the details of your container this is hard to answer, but your workspace folder should be just the folder containing the scripts you are modifying - don't include the python interpreter or venv files or any of the unrelated folders within your docker container.  If your workspace is the root directory of the container, then you're including the entire Ubuntu distro as part of your workspace, leading to the workspace size issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).